# PHP if not statements

Tags: php, if-statement, conditional-operator

This may be the way my server is set up, but I'm banging my head against the wall. I'm trying to say that if `$action` has no value or has a value that is not "add" or "delete" then have an error, else keep running the script. However, I get an error no matter what `$action` is.

```
 $action = $_GET['a'];
 if((!isset($action)) || ($action != "add" || $action != "delete")){
     //header("location:index.php");
     echo "error <br>";
 }
```

`$action` is being set properly and if run something like `if($action =="add")` it works. This is on my local host, so it could be a settings issue.

Comment: there is no sense in checking if $action is set, if you set it on the previous line

Comment: Shrapnel, if nothing is in the `"?a=xxx"` part of the url `$action` should be null. I think if I was setting `$action` to a static variable you would be right. Yet, because the user enters data there is a chance for problems. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: oops, my bad. isset() return false on null variables. Anyway you should check if $_GET['a'] set, not $action. Or you will get "Undefined index" error.

Comment: Can you explain the "index not set" error? I've never heard of that.

Comment: `error_reporting(E_ALL);` <- just add this line to your config file/top of script and see what really happens in your code :)

Comment: I have all error reporting on and it ran just fine... wierd. I added the line to the top of the file and still ran.

Comment: well you have either display_errors off or call your script with  $_GET['a']; set. otherwise you will get `Notice: Undefined index: a in ...` error

Comment: @Col Actually there is sense because `isset` also checks for `null`.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Your logic is slightly off. The second `||` should be `&&`:

```
if ((!isset($action)) || ($action != "add" && $action != "delete"))
```

You can see why your original line fails by trying out a sample value. Let's say `$action` is `"delete"`. Here's how the condition reduces down step by step:

```
// $action == "delete"
if ((!isset($action)) || ($action != "add" || $action != "delete"))
if ((!true) || ($action != "add" || $action != "delete"))
if (false || ($action != "add" || $action != "delete"))
if ($action != "add" || $action != "delete")
if (true || $action != "delete")
if (true || false)
if (true)
```

Oops! The condition just succeeded and printed "error", but it was supposed to fail. In fact, if you think about it, no matter what the value of `$action` is, one of the two `!=` tests will return true. Switch the `||` to `&&` and then the second to last line becomes `if (true && false)`, which properly reduces to `if (false)`.

There is a way to use `||` and have the test work, by the way. You have to negate everything else using [De Morgan's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws), i.e.:

```
if ((!isset($action)) || !($action == "add" || $action == "delete"))
```

You can read that in English as "if action is not (either add or remove), then".

Answer (score 11):

No matter what $action is, it will always either not be "add" OR not be "delete", which is why the if condition always passes. What you want is to use && instead of ||:

```
(!isset($action)) || ($action !="add" && $action !="delete"))
```

Comment: @dumbledor I think this was the easiest way to modify my original code and explain what I did wrong.

Answer (score 3):

You're saying "if it's not set or it's different from add or it's different from delete". You realize that `a != x && a != y`, with `x != y` is necessarily `false` since `a` cannot be simultaneously two different values.

Answer (score 3):

You could also try:

```
if ((!isset($action)) || !($action == "add" || $action == "delete")) {
  // Do your stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, you can quickly create a truth table to check if it evaluates the way you want...  it's kind of like [Sudoku](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudoku).

```
(!isset($action)) && ($action != "add" && $action != "delete"))
```

Example:

`column 1 is issetaction, column 2 and 3 evaluates !="add","delete" respectively`

if($a=add) T && (F && T) => T && F => FALSE

if($a=delete) T && (T && F) => T && F => FALSE

if($a=nothing) T && (T && T) => T && T => TRUE

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the best and easiest way to do it:

```
if (!(isset($action) && ($action == "add" || $action == "delete")))
```

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, but just for the sake of code formatting

```
if((isset($_GET['a'])) $action=$_GET['a']; else $action ="";
if(!($action === "add" OR $action === "delete")){
  header("location: /index.php");
  exit;
}
```

Note the `exit;` statement after header(). That's the important thing. header() does not terminate script execution.