# Using multiple OR in a If Statement in PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, logical-operators

On our website (wordpress site)

I am trying to create a page and I am trying to remove some HTML from being implemented on some of the pages.

This code is from my header.php file

This is the current working code

```
<?php if(!Is_front_page() || !is_page('my-page-1') || !is_page('my-page-2')) : ?>
 <div class="breadcump1" style="margin-top: 50px">
   <div class="page-wrapper">
     <div class="page-body">
       <article id="post-814" class="post-814 page type-page status-publish hentry">
       <div class="container" >
         <?php if (function_exists('qt_custom_breadcrumbs')) qt_custom_breadcrumbs(); ?>
       </div>
       </article>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Thecode above works. The html is not implemented on the home page.
However, I also want to eliminate the code for two other pages (my-page-1  my-page-2)

```
<?php if(!Is_front_page() || !is_page('my-page-1') || !is_page('my-page-2')) : ?>
```

But, I cant seem to get it to work. What am I doing wrong with the ORs?

Thanx

Comment: Replace `||` with `&&`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP if not statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3376945/php-if-not-statements)

Comment: Read it as you'd say it. `if not this AND not this AND not this`.

Comment: you have to use `&&` or `AND` instead of **OR**

Comment: Note that you have `Is_front_page()` in there, it should be `is_front_page()` instead.

Comment: @cabrerahector Why? Those are the same thing

Comment: Technically that's true: while PHP is sensitive case with variables, when it comes to functions the language doesn't care how you write them (lower case, upper case, etc). Personally I'd rather see functions being called in the same way they were declared for consistency. There's also the chance that PHP one day decides function calls should also be case sensitive - if that ever happens, your code will break and it might take you a while to figure out why @user3783243.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you do not want the html displayed in none of these pages you could just use && ( AND).
I think it is more intuitive.

"If it is not front page AND is not 'my-page-1' AND is not 'my-page-2' show the page"

```
<?php if(!Is_front_page() && !is_page('my-page-1') && !is_page('my-page-2')) : ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Basics of logic !(A || B) = !A && !B:

```
<?php if(!Is_front_page() && !is_page('my-page-1') && !is_page('my-page-2')) : ?>
```